# c++ repaint window

Tags: c++, winapi, window, repaint

i got a window with an image in it. but when its a little picture i first need to resize the window before i can see it, the screen doesnt refresh/repaint.
how can i fix this?

Comment: What operating system, GUI, programming environment, etc ?

Comment: win32 normal hwnd with createwindowex

Comment: I think we need to see some code here. Perhaps in order to scale the picture you are using the window size before it has been established You should get a WM_Resize as the window is created

Answer (score 4):

You can force a window to refresh by calling [`RedrawWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162911%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

to repaint you should use the InvalidateRect(). it will send message to WM_REPAINT to force it repaint

Answer (score 1):

This very much depends on what technology/tools you are using. On Windows, this is done by processing WM_PAINT message, or better, by using a 3rd-party control that does it for you.